# Why some phrasal verbs can be conjugated

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Why examples 2,3,6 can use conjugated phrasal verb but example 4 not use conjugated verb?

1. I had had chocolates dry up in races before.
2. I had had chocolates dried up in races before.
3. I had had cookies cooked up in salt in races before.
4. I had had cookies cook up in salt in races before.
5. I had had batteries heat up in races before.
6. I had had batteries heated up in races before.

Okay, let's have some new examples.

7. I had a water bottle **dry up** in the race.
8. I had a water bottle **dried up** in the race.
9. I had food **cooked up** in olive oil in the race.
10. I had food **cook up** in olive oil in the race.
11. I had a water bottle **freeze up** in the race.
12. I had a water bottle **froze up** in the race.
13. I had a water bottle **frozen up** in the race.

Why example 9 is correct and 10 is wrong? Why 13 is correct?

Comment: Those sentences are quite off. And what's with the "had had" in every example? [Grammar correction: Why do examples 2, 3 and 4 use [whatever]

Comment: dry up: The rain left many puddles but they dried up. Try to use sentences that would sound a little better...cook up in salt is meaningless. You could have just used the simple past.

Comment: Please use sentences with clear and sensible meaning. I have no idea what it means for a chocolate to dry up in a race.

Comment: Rocky, I've closed this question for **needs details or clarity** for these reasons: (1) the example sentences are nonsense, so we cannot be sure we understand the intended meaning; (2) you say that phrasal verbs 2, 3 and 6 can conjugate, but none of the phrasal verbs are conjugated -- only the verb "have" is conjugated; (3) you say that 4 is somehow different to 2, 3 and 6, but it's not clear how and you don't explain.

Comment: Why specifically do you think that 4 and 10 are wrong?

Comment: @gotube I don't think 4 and 10 are wrong but when I checked on Grammarly and Quillbot they both showed error.

Comment: @gotube You answered my previous question that we use only one conjugated verb in a clause. So why can't we use base form of verb 'cook' in 4 and 10?

Comment: @Rocky Ahhh. You should have led with "Grammarly". It's good, but it makes mistakes. In this case, it doesn't seem aware that "cook" can be used in this way. It's really awkward, and the sentence itself makes no sense to me (you "bake" cookies, not "cook" them; you don't bake them in salt; and you don't do so during a race), but the grammar with "cook" is technically correct, even though it's just about never used in that way.

Answer (score 1):

All phrasal verbs conjugate:

> I take off my sweater
> He takes off  his sweater

etc

Here this isn't conjugation.  It is two similar constructions:

> have {something} do {something}

and

> have {something} done

The latter uses the past participle for a passive sense of the clause.

Your examples are all weird, perhaps with the exception of the batteries example, so lets look at that.  I'll remove the irrelevant past perfect that is just distracting:

> I had batteries heat up in the race.

This mean that during the race the batteries became hot, presumably as a result of racing.  This is what wikitionary describes as "To be affected by an occurrence."  *The hospital had several patients contract pneumonia last week.*

> I had batteries heated up in the race.

This means that somebody heated up the batteries, at your instruction.  I suppose a driver might say "If you need to change batteries during a race it is important that they are warm.  I've had batteries heated up during the race to make sure."  The passive voice implies an actor, so "someone must heat up the batteries".

This is possible due to the labile nature of "heat up".  You can say both  "I heat up" (that is I become warm) and "I heat up something" (that is the something becomes warm).

This labile quality of "heat up" is why it can be used in both  "I had batteries heat up" and "I had batteries heated up".

Other lablile verbs can function similarly:

> Last night I had the fake door open during a performance.  You could see the stage hand listening to music behind it.

> Last night I had the fake door opened during the performance, to let more light onto the stage.

But none of these examples are common

Comment: This is a comment on the question, not an answer about the difference between 4 vs. 2, 3, and 6 in terms of conjugation

Comment: It's also "had had", not just "had".

Comment: @gotube I rather disagree.  Firstly I note that conjugation is the wrong word to use.  The I explain why I'm not going to use a past perfect construction.  Then I look at why in some examples the past participle form can be used.  And I answer the question: it is due to the labile nature of certain verbs.

Comment: @JamesK I hear you. You don't even mention sentence 4 though. Is the OP supposed to draw the inference that "cook" is *not* a labile verb? (It is labile, BTW). Anyway, someone else has put this in the review queue, so I'll let that take its natural course.